# Adding to Python Path with Bash

Tags: python, bash, pythonpath

I'm trying to add to a script my advisor gave me and could use a hand. Here's the code:

```
  5 if [[ -f /home/blstaff/anaconda_setup ]]; then
  6     echo "Setup!"
  7     source /home/blstaff/anaconda_setup
  8     REBORN=/home/brown/hi/there/reborn
  9     ANALYSIS=/home/brown/hi/there/wazzup/analysis/
 10     export PYTHONPATH=$REBORN:$PYTHONPATH
 11     export PYTHONPATH=$ANALYSIS:$PYTHONPATH
 12     export PS1='rhods-sacla> '
 13 fi
```

The parts I added were the `ANALYSIS` and subsequent `export` line, the `REBORN` parts worked previously.  I'm unable to import the `analysis` module when importing in python.

I'm not sure how detailed to be with this question, since it could be a simple syntax thing I'm overlooking. If I need to add any detail, please let me know and I'll post an edit to this question.

Comment: what is the content of the directory `/home/brown/hi/there/wazzup/analysis/` or what is the output of ```ls -l /home/brown/hi/there/wazzup/analysis/```?

Comment: There are a couple folders and some other python scripts. I'm trying to call a script that is directly located in `analysis`. i.e., `../../analysis/myscript.py`

Comment: @warungman does my response help?

Comment: `import alanysis` will generate error then, but you should be able to do `import myscript`